# Django: Celery import causes error while executing cron commands

Tags: python, django, cron, celery

Recently installed celery on django, it works fine, but I realized that my cron (I mean usual cron, not celery's periodic tasks) commands doesn't execute.
I had lines in my cron like this:

```
sudo -u someuser python /home/someuser/django_proj/manage.py somecommand --settings=someapp.settings
```

And it works very well. But if I add "import djcelery" to settings.py, I will have this error:

```
Unknown command: 'somecommand'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

What am I doing wrong?
P.S. I know, that celery has periodic tasks, but I can't use this feature right now.

Also, I have "common_settings.py" file, and someapp/settings.py has this code:

```
from common_settings import *
```

If I add "import djcelery" to common_settings.py I will got this:

> Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing '/home/someuser/django_proj/manage.py'. It appears you've customized things. You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module. (If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)

It tries to find settings in django_proj folder, but I don't have any settings here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks, like you're not installed your application correctly. For example you may forgot comma in INSTALLED_APPS, and your previous application is not activating when django starts. 
No any reasons to get it broken.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am not sure that this error happens because of comma or anything else. The difference between "ok" settings file and "broken" settings file is that "broken" file has "import djcelery" and that's all.